# Unit test existence of a directory - Junit

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing

I have a function that I use to detect whether a certain directory path exists. Here's the function:

```
public boolean isRunningOnSandbox() {
   return Files.isDirectory(Paths.get("/mySandbox/cloud/sandbox"));
}
```

As you can see, it relies on static method isDirectory. In my team, we do not use PowerMock for testing.

So, how can I test this method? I have tried writing a test like:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder;

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    File parent = new File("/");
    temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder(parent);
    temporaryFolder.create();
    File folder = temporaryFolder.newFolder("mySandbox", "cloud", "sandbox");
    subject.isRunningOnSandbox();
}
```

But, I get an error

```
ava.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

because it doesn't let me create a temporary folder under the root. I am guessing there is a better way to test this code instead of trying to create a folder.

Comment: I would lean towards allowing injection of the value and verifying the method call using a `tempdir` and asserting that the `isRunningOnSandbox` returns true when using the tempdir and false when not, and then an additional test verifying the value in each region/env/space/whatever via another test.

Comment: Are you willing to refactor this tightly coupled code and use dependency inversion in order to isolate code under test? Current example is more of an integration test if accessing actual folder.

Comment: I think you need to also handle that exception and return `false` in case of `Permissions denied` exception.

Comment: please use the proper tags, this is not a unit test, but an integration test

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, onee of them migh be like the below one.
Assumming that `isRunningOnSandbox` method is in some class `SomeClass`, then refactor this class in this way:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public boolean isRunningOnSandbox() {
        return Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(getSanboxPath()));
    }

    protected String getSanboxPath(){
        return "/mySandbox/cloud/sandbox";
    }
}
```

and then in your tests inject into this class another directory  to which you have access, for example:

```
public class SomeClassTest {

    class SomeClassToTest extends SomeClass{
        String folder;
        public SomeClassToTest(String folder){
            this.folder = folder;
        }
        @Override
        protected String getSanboxPath(){
            return folder;
        }
    }

    static String sandboxFolder = "myTestSandobxFolder";

    static Path tempDir;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createFolder() throws IOException {
        tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory(sandboxFolder);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void deleteFolder() throws IOException {
        Files.delete(tempDir);
    }

    @Test
    public void IsRunningOnSandbox_shouldReturnTrueWhenPathExists() throws IOException {
        //given
        SomeClass testedObject = new SomeClassToTest(tempDir.toString());
       //when
        boolean result = testedObject.isRunningOnSandbox();
        //then
        assertThat(result).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void IsRunningOnSandbox_shouldReturnFalseWhenPathDoesNotExist() throws IOException {
        //given
        SomeClass testedObject = new SomeClassToTest("/abcdef123");
        //when
        boolean result = testedObject.isRunningOnSandbox();
        //then
        assertThat(result).isFalse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you have shown is not suited for unit-testing: With unit-testing you try to find the bugs in small, isolated software pieces. But, which bugs could be in this example code that are not related to the other components, that is, the `Files` component, the `Paths` component and the actual file system?

The potential bugs in your example are about questions like "am I calling the right functions?" or "do I call the functions with proper values for the arguments?" or "do the functions I call return arguments as I expect" or "am I using the path that is also the path found in the file system".  This can not be checked with unit-testing, but with integraton-testing.

Imagine you have the wrong path in mind.  Then, in your unit-test you would also check against the same wrong path, and your unit-test would succeed.  Only when running that test as an integration test on the real file system you could figure out that the path which you had in mind was wrong and did not match the actual path in the file system.